# SetTimeout in socket.io doesn't working the first time

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am working on a solution to fetch an ip adress from a node server hosted on dynamic ip. The problem i have is the function setTimeout doesn't work in server side on the first lauch. I must do a refresh to see it working.

Server side code :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

  setTimeout(function() {
    ip = socket.handshake.headers.host;
    socket.broadcast.emit('ip', {ip: ip})
  }, 30000);

});
```

Client side code

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('ip', function(data){;
  alert(data.ip);
});
```

In fact on the first launch of my client, the alert or console.log doesn't show me the ip adress. If i make a refresh of the page all work fine.

Have you a solution for me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're not emitting to the socket that just connected but to all other sockets, so you must have a second connection to the server before you receive an `"ip"` message client side.

Change

```
socket.broadcast.emit('ip', {ip: ip})
```

to

```
socket.emit('ip', {ip: ip})
```

Comment: Hello thanks but your answer resole a part of my problem. In fact if i use emit instead broadast.emit, i receivre the ip adress, but i reveive it only the first time i load the page. the timeout must give me the ip address every 30 seconds. Have you a solution  ? Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear but maybe you want `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: tôôooooh ! (i am simpson)